# NSDateFormatter milliseconds bug

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I want to create a NSDateFormatter that should parse dates like this "2014-05-13 23:31:41.374577". So:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS";
NSString *dateString = @"2014-05-13 23:31:41.374577";
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSString *anotherDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

However, the `anotherDateString` is `2014-05-13 23:31:41.374000`. Why does it truncate the milliseconds?

Comment: Maybe nitpicking here, but it seems to keep the milliseconds and truncate the microseconds.

Comment: Is the error in `dateFromString` or `stringFromDate`? Does your `[date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]` have as many decimal places as you expect?

Comment: It seems that `[date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]` is already rounded to 3 decimal places ...

Comment: NSTimeInterval in iOS is measured in milliseconds. Unlike java and some other languages where it is measured in nanoseconds. This will be where the difference comes from.

Comment: @Fogmeister: `NSTimeInterval` is a double and has a higher precision. You can also convert between `NSDate` and `NSTimeInterval` with more than millisecond precision. The problem here seems to be the date formatter.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems that `NSDateFormatter` works only with millisecond resolution, for the
following reasons:

- By setting a breakpoint in `CFDateFormatterCreateDateFromString`, one can 
  see that this function is called from `dateFromString:`:

  ```
  (lldb) bt
  * thread #1: tid = 0x26d03f, 0x018f47d0 CoreFoundation`CFDateFormatterCreateDateFromString, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 3.1
      frame #0: 0x018f47d0 CoreFoundation`CFDateFormatterCreateDateFromString
      frame #1: 0x0116e0ea Foundation`getObjectValue + 248
      frame #2: 0x0116dfc7 Foundation`-[NSDateFormatter getObjectValue:forString:errorDescription:] + 206
      frame #3: 0x0116879f Foundation`-[NSDateFormatter dateFromString:] + 71
    * frame #4: 0x00002d56 foo`main(argc=1, argv=0xbfffee54) + 182 at main.mm:25
  ```
- `CFDateFormatterCreateDateFromString()` is from 
  [CFDateFormatter.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.19/CFDateFormatter.c)
  which is open source. One can see that all calendrical calculations are made using the
  [ICU Calendar Classes](http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime/calendar).
- It is stated in [calendar.h](https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/ICU/ICU-6.2.6/icuSources/i18n/unicode/calendar.h) that `Calendar` uses `UDate` which has a millisecond resolution:

  ```
  /**
   * <code>Calendar</code> is an abstract base class for converting between
   * a <code>UDate</code> object and a set of integer fields such as
   * <code>YEAR</code>, <code>MONTH</code>, <code>DAY</code>, <code>HOUR</code>,
   * and so on. (A <code>UDate</code> object represents a specific instant in
   * time with millisecond precision. See UDate
   * for information about the <code>UDate</code> class.)
   * ...
  ```