# ISO8601DateFormatter in swift lost nanoseconds

Tags: swift, datetime, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to parse date with folloing code:

```
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
dateFormatter.formatOptions = [ .withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds ]

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2019-01-30T23:51:55.650144Z")
let string = dateFormatter.string(from: date) // 2019-01-30T23:51:55.650Z
```

Input date:

> 2019-01-30T23:51:55.**650**144Z

But output date is:

> 2019-01-30T23:51:55.**650**Z

This is keep only 3 digits in fractional part.

How to avoid it?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684727/nsdateformatter-milliseconds-bug